# How can I make my nested table fill up the table cell it's in?

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
<table border="1"><td>

<table border="1"><tr>

    <td>A</td>

    <td>
        <table border="1"><tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>B</b></td>
            <td><b>C</b></td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>E</b></td>
            <td><b>F</b></td>
            <td>G</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>H</b></td>
            <td><b>I</b></td>
            <td>K</td>
        </tr>

        </tr></table>
    </td>

</tr></table>

<table border="1"><tr>
    <td style="width:600px;">L</td>
    <td>M</td>
</tr></table>
```

I am trying to make it like this: [image]

Can somerone please help?

Comment: it might be prudent to look at `rowspan` and `colspan` and generally improving your `html` markup.

Comment: Look closely at your markup. Make sure your opening tags are matched by closing tags, and look for the right table structure throughout. `<td>` can't follow directly from `<table`, for example.

Comment: OK, i fixed the td issue but i still don't get the result i want... :(

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: the 600px is just for example, i can't set td to 600px and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [Fillde Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y26z/) !

Here is code

```
<table border="1"><td>

<table border="1" width="100%"><tr>

<td>A</td>

<td >
    <table border="1" align="right"><tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>B</b></td>
        <td><b>C</b></td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>E</b></td>
        <td><b>F</b></td>
        <td>G</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>H</b></td>
        <td><b>I</b></td>
        <td>K</td>
    </tr>

    </tr></table>
</td>

 </tr></table>

<table border="1"><tr>
<td style="width:600px;">L</td>
<td>M</td>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>

        <table border="1" align="left">
            <tr>

            <td style="width:550px;">A</td>

            <td style="width:50px;" align="left">
                <table  border="1"  align="left">

                <tr >
                    <td><b>B</b></td>
                    <td><b>C</b></td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><b>E</b></td>
                    <td><b>F</b></td>
                    <td>G</td>
                 </tr>

                <tr>
                     <td><b>H</b></td>
                    <td><b>I</b></td>
                    <td>K</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</td>
</tr></table>

<table border="1"><tr>
    <td style="width:600px;">L</td>
    <td>M</td>
</tr></table>try out this

just make td align left..

    <table border="1"><td>

    <table border="1"><tr>

        <td>A</td>

        <td align="left">
            <table border="1"><tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>B</b></td>
                <td><b>C</b></td>
                <td>D</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>E</b></td>
                <td><b>F</b></td>
                <td>G</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><b>H</b></td>
                <td><b>I</b></td>
                <td>K</td>
            </tr>

            </tr></table>
        </td>

    </tr></table>

    <table border="1"><tr>
        <td style="width:600px;">L</td>
        <td>M</td>
    </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the inner table an attribute `width="600px;"`